Equivalent conditions for morphism between affine commutative group schemes to be an epimophism
I'm reading the book "Lectures on p-Divisible Groups" written by Michel Demazure. It claims on page 31 that a morphism between two affine commutative group schemes is an epimorphism iff the map on structure sheaves induced by the morphism is injective. However, I can't figure out why. As well known, injectivity on structure sheaves only implies the morphism is dominant.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Are you over a field? What does affine group schemes mean?

Yes, it is over a field. By affine group schemes, I just want to say an affine scheme with group structure.

If $k$ is a commutative ring, then the monos in the category of commutative $k$-algebras are precisely the injective $k$-algebra homomorphisms. Therefore these correspond precisely to the epis in the category of affine $k$-schemes. What isn't obvious to me is that this characterization remains true when restricting to the subcategory of commutative affine $k$-group schemes, or, dually, when restricting to the category of bicommutative $k$-Hopf algebras.

Are epimorphisms between affine schemes required to be surjective or just dominant? Because in the general category of group schemes, I remember epimorphisms are defined to require the morphisms are surjective as written in Mumford's Abelian Varieties.

@Taozipeter Assuming you mean finite type, injective is equivalent to faithfully flat (which is easily seen to correspond to an epimorphism). See Proposition 5.43 of Milne's book on algebraic groups (the published version). In any case, your dominance vs. surjectivity is a non-issue as the image of algebraic group maps are closed (see Proposition 1.68 of op. cit.).

@AlexYoucis, can you offer me a link to get the published version of Milne's book? I only the version in 2015.

@Taozipeter No, unfortunately not. But, you should be able to find a copy on your own, or find these results elsewhere (e.g., the preliminary version on his website, or Borel’s book or Demazure—Gabriel or…).

OK, thank you very much.
